# For in don't iterate again over a file with nested loop - Python

Tags: python

I have a users.txt and password.txt and i need to iterate in both files

Example of users.txt:

- root
- admin
- oracle
- users

Example of password.txt

- toor
- rooot
- administrator
- password

In my loop just print the first user "root" and all of the password but dont 
print the others users, this is my code:

```
fu = open("/home/dskato/diccionarios/user.txt", "r")
fp = open("/home/dskato/diccionarios/pasword.txt", "r")

for user in fu.readlines():
  for password in fp.readlines():
    print "Username: "+user+" Password: "+password
```

This is the output but don't iterate over the others users 
What it's wrong?

Username: root
 Password: 123456

Username: root
 Password: 12345678

Username: root
 Password: 12345678

Username: root
 Password: 1234

Username: root
 Password: pass

Username: root
 Password: password

And i need this output example:

- root: 123456
- root:password
- root:toor
- admin:123456
- admin:password
- admin:toor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over all the passwords with the inner loop on the first iteration of the outer loop. On the second iteration of the outer loop, there are no more passwords to iterate (`fp`'s current position is at the end of the file).

You could [`fp.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to reset `fp` after each user iteration:

```
for user in fu:
    for password in fp:
        print "Username: " + user.rstrip('\n') + " Password: " + password.rstrip('\n')
    fp.seek(0)
```

Or you could read the passwords once into a list:

```
passwords = list(fp)

for user in fu:
    for password in passwords:
        print "Username: " + user.rstrip('\n') + " Password: " + password.rstrip('\n')
```

There's a tradeoff between file access and memory usage here.

Comment: this is the output root:123, admin:pass,  And i need to iterate the users again with the password, like root:123, root:pass, root:toor, admin:123, admin:pass, admin:toor

Comment: You want every user with every password? If so, please update your question to clarify.

Comment: Yes  i need that, i edited now

Comment: no nee to use `readlines`, it is inefficient.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the updated question and incorporate feedback from @juanpa.arrivillaga.

Comment: This  works Thanks :D @Galen

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested for loop, which reads passwords (in the internal loop), for each users (in the external loop).

What happened now, your external loop read first user (root), and the internal read all password, and print them together with root.

When your external loops tries to process second user, your password file is already reaching the end, nothing is printed.

You need to read lines of these files separately, store it in an array and print later.

Better yet, just use paste : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234208/combining-several-files-into-a-single-csv

Comment: `paste` doesn't perform nested loops.It just "zips" the data together.

Comment: Indeed, I did not notice the example outputs, (or it was edited after I answered). Now trying different passwords for each users is not something I am familiar with :P

Comment: same for me. Even got 2 upvotes for a wrong answer. Deleted it.